# ubuntu wont acces 1 TB hdd

Tags: hard-drive

I cannot acces my 1 TB hdd and keep getting this message :

*Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb2: Command-line `mount "/media/Big_Data"' exited with non-zero exit status 12: NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?*

is there any work around for this, my machine is Ubuntu 15.04 with 3.19.21 kernel

Comment: Often NTFS signature is the Partition boot sector of the drive that must be seen as NTFS, even if just data. How did you format? Did you overwrite partition boot sector? Even if not bootable add boot flag and run chkdsk from a Windows repair CD or flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

You fixing a corrupted HDD Partition with:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb2
```

This is [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/ntfsfix.8.html) for you

if you not install ntfsfix, you can install with command:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfsfix
```

Comment: actually i did,
and I got this message :

<i>  Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk. </i>